# Unfamiliar Code Snippet /\b[a-z]/g

Tags: javascript

I have seen the following code snippet used by other programmers in questions I am answering on coderbyte in javascript : `/\b[a-z]/g`
Can someone explain what this means / when it can be used?

Comment: This is called a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 4):

It's a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), composed of a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), as a [regexp literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression).

In can be used to detect all lowercase letters at the beginning of a word.

Answer (score 1):

This is regexp(regular expression).

http://www.regexr.com/

```
/[SOME CONTENT]/
```

**"/"** means inner content is regExp

then last **"g"** means search global

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression.

```
/\b[a-z]/g
```

selects the first letter of a word if it is lowercase

See below for an example of it being run on [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/)

[image]